# PDFDestination is not giving me the right information (Apple PDFKit)

Tags: ios, pdf, pspdfkit, ios-pdfkit, apple-pdfkit

I've got a PDF file of a technical drawing that contains one page with bookmarks linking to specific areas of the document.

When I click those bookmarks in Adobe Reader or Foxit Reader, it zooms to this specified area. But in Apple's Preview.app or iBooks or a PDFKit based iOS-App it won't work. Even PSPDFKit can't handle those bookmarks.

I'm building a `PDFView` based iOS-App that can handle those bookmarks. When I debug the `PDFOutline` property I can see that the contained `PDFDestination` object contains the information, but in private fields. I can watch them during debugging.

[image]

Also when I access the `description` property of the `PDFDestination` object, I'm getting the following:

```
FitR, page = 0, l = 132.0, b = 451.0, r = 400.0, t = 724.0
```

But the values `zoom` and `point` return `3.40282347e+38F` which is the max value of `CGFloat` on 32-bit systems which means they're not properly set.

---

#### `PDFView` Config

Here's a litte more code, showing how I configured my `PDFView`

```
pdfView.document = document
pdfView.displayDirection = .horizontal
pdfView.autoScales = true
pdfView.usePageViewController(true, withViewOptions: nil)
pdfView.enableDataDetectors = false

pdfThumbnailView.thumbnailSize = CGSize(width: 44, height: 32)
pdfThumbnailView.pdfView = pdfView
pdfThumbnailView.layoutMode = .horizontal
```

#### Go to `PDFOutline`

```
// Load the first outline element
let outline = document.outlineRoot?.child(at: 0)?.child(at: 0)
let destination = outline!.destination

// This way to access the destination yields in the same thing
let destinationViaAction = (outline?.action as? PDFActionGoTo)?.destination

// Nothing happens here...
pdfView.go(to: destinationViaAction!)
// nor here
pdfView.go(to: destination!)
```

---

#### Questions

1. Is it a bug in PDFKit that the properties `zoom` and `point` of `PDFDestination` are not correctly calculated by those existing inset values?
2. Am I allowed to parse the `description` of `PDFDestination` and work with those values? Or will Apple refuse my App because of accessing private information?

---

#### Update

I filed a bug at Apple and will update this question when I get a response.

Comment: will Apple refuse my App because of accessing private information -> only refuse if you not provide perfect reason or you not mention in app description that your app access this private information for this purpose.

Comment: pdfview.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
        pdfview.autoScales = true add this 2 line in your code i'm not get any zoom scale in my project Optional(XYZ, page = 0, left = 0.0, top = 841.9, zoom = N/A
)

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya I tried your suggestion but it didn't work out

Comment: can you share your snapcode that you use so we can identify your problem.

Comment: I added a little more code, how I configured `PDFView`. But since Apple's own apps and PSPDFKit doesn't support those links, I assume that I can't configure PDFKit to support it.